# How to parse <media:content> in RSS using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Am trying to parse the RSS feed from www.ted.com/talks/rss, I can access all normal tags using E4X but I have no idea how one parses the  tags!

For example the

This is my code and I can traverse easily but I want to pull the media:content tags.

```
    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point

        var _loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var _request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.ted.com/talks/rss");
        _loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOErrorHandler);
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
        _loader.load(_request);
    }

    private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
    {
        var _rssXML:XMLList =  new XMLList(e.target.data);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++ ) 
        {
            //trace(_rssXML.channel.item.link[i]);
            trace(_rssXML.channel.item[i]);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your using MRSS specifications. You want to look into QName to access qualifying namespaces

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/QName.html

Comment: Thanks only I used namespace creation. I didn't know about Qname.

The code for anyone in the future:
private var _media:Namespace = new Namespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");

_rssXML =  new XML(e.target.data);
   _rssList = new XMLList(_rssXML.channel.item);
   _array = new Array();
   for (var i:int = 0; i < _rssList.length(); i++) 
   {
    _array.push(_rssList.._media::content.@url[i]);
   }